# Locally change the behavior of the underscore in the math mode to group all the successive characters in the subscript

Tags: math-mode, macros, tex-core

I would like to know if it is possible to have a switch (e.g. `\myswitch`) that:

1- changes the behavior of underscore `_` **only in math mode** such that all the following characters are grouped into a single subscript while terminating the subscript processing when encountering the first white space.

2- **locally** affects the math mode inside the parent environment or group without interaction with any math content outside the parent environment or group in which it was switched on.

3- accepts an optional wrapping command. For example, `\myswitch[1][\mathit]` means that the all the subscript is wrapped in `\mathit{<all the subscript characters>}` by default, and `\myswitch[]` will not format the subscript but group the subscript characters as long as the switch is on.

4- is able to include white space in the subscript without treating it as the terminating character when the subscript is wrapped in a pair of curly braces `{}`.

For example,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
    
    Before switching it on\\
    \verb|$A_BCD$| should yield the same output of \verb|$A_B CD$|\\
    
    Enabling the switch inside an environment or group\\
    \verb*|\begin{some environemnt} or \begingroup|\\
    Switch it on here\\
    \verb|$A_BCD E_FGH$| should yield the same output of \verb|$A_\mathit{BCD} E_\mathit{FGH}$|\\
    
    Change the default \verb|\mathit| to wrap the subscript in, for example, \verb|\mathrm|\\
    \verb|$A_BCD E_FGH$| should yield the same output of \verb|$A_\mathrm{BCD} E_\mathrm{FGH}$|\\
    
    Spaces can be included if the subscript is wrapped in a pair of curly braces\\
    \verb|$A_{B CD}$| will yield the same output of \verb|$A_\mathit{B CD}$|\\
    
    Disabling the default optional argument will remove the effect of \verb|\mathit|\\
    \verb|$A_BCD E_FGH$| should yield the same output of \verb|$A_{BCD} E_{FGH}$|\\
    \verb*|\end{some environemnt} or \endgroup|\\
    
    Even it is left switched on in another environment/group, it has no effect outside it\\
    \verb|$A_BCD$| should yield the same output of \verb|$A_B CD$|\\
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: anything is possible (almost none of the normal tex syntax is built in) but white space is always ignored in math mode so making it significant terminator in this way will confuse anything reading the code, co-authors, other latex package, syntax highlighting in editors etc. Are you sure you want this syntax?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right about treating the white space as terminating character. Maybe another terminating character should be considered.

Comment: Are you willing and able to use LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @Mico I use lualatex by default :)

Comment: @Diaa what is wrong with `}` as a terminating character?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Nothing wrong with it, but the main idea was to fasten the typing by not thinking about the terminating characters.

Comment: Assuming that terminating the subscript at spaces is good syntax, how do you cope with `x_\vee +y` where ***there is no space***? TeX will not even see the space after `\vee`, which is removed before making tokens. And no, using two spaces is not a remedy. Good LaTeX editors will allow automatically adding braces after `_` and placing the cursor in the middle.

Comment: @egreg is it somehow safe to use semicolon `;` as the terminating character? but I will face the problem of how to escape it in case I need to type it in the subscript. I know there is no absolutely safe approach; my main target is to fasten the typing without messing up my whole document. That's why I need its effect to be local.

Comment: @Diaa if you type more than one line of latex you have to be aware of matching `{..}` so using `{}` is perfectly natural and any latex user can read it. Just arbitrarily using a completely different syntax idiom in parts of the document makes the source file harder to read and harder to work with and much harder to incorporate fragments into other documents should that need occur later. Every language has its idioms, latex is backslash and braces. Your question is like "how do I use Fortran  syntax in some function in my C code."